# Do postgre have map and set structure(like STL in C++)?

Tags: postgresql, stl

I need to add a feature in postgre, and I want to realize the feature with map and set structure(like STL in C++). Do postgre realize the map structure and set structure in C? Where can I find the functions?

What I need in the code is just like this:

```
map<char*,set<char*> >
set<char*>
```

Comment: The language of databases is SQL, which doesn't have maps and sets. It has one-to-many relations and unique constraints. Consider doing an [introduction to SQL](https://www.coursera.org/learn/intro-sql).

Comment: I'm asking about the kernel of postgre, not how to use postgre. Postgre is writen by C. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Ah, so you're editing the Postgres source code?  Have a look at the mailing lists at https://www.postgresql.org/list/